# Mongodb (mongoose) aggregate is returning the JSON given instead of the sum asked for

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am an extreme newbie to MongDB - using mongoose npm module in my node.js app

given the following data:

```
    _id:622e41bf09c90e08689eb0aa
     title:"amazon"
     start:"2022-03-13 12:10:55"
     amount:"14.11"

    _id:622e41bf09c90e08689eb0ab
     title:"amazon"
     start:"2022-03-13 12:10:55"
     amount:"14.11"
     const db = mongoose.model('upgrade', schema);

     const sum = db.aggregate(
       [{ 
         $project : { 
           _id: '$_id', 
           total : {  
             $sum: "amount" 
           }
         }
       }]);
        console.log(__line__, sum._pipeline[0].$project);
        // 143 { _id: '$_id', total: { '$sum': '$amount' } }
```

what I would like to see in the results is the total of the 2 amounts (28.22)

Can someone please help me get the right syntax to get the desired result?
I really like the idea of working with JSON as opposed to RDBMS
Thank you!

**UPDATE**

```
  const sum = db.aggregate([{ $group : { _id: null, total : {  $sum: { $toDouble : "$amount" }}}}]);
```

still logging: 143 { _id: null, total: { '$sum': { '$toDouble': '$amount' } } }

**UPDATE 2**
I have just added things to the schema definition:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  title: String,
  amount: mongoose.Decimal128,
  start: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

but I am still just getting an empty array in the log
**UPDATE 3**
console.log(**line**, mongoose.connection.readyState); shows connecting (2) - so there must be something wrong with my connection string

Comment: Not Mongoose developer. But your aggregate query should use `$group` instead of `$project`. And you need to cast the `amount` to double/float first. `{ $group : { _id: null',  total : {  $sum: { $toDouble: "$amount" } } } }`

Comment: Thanks @YongShun, but see my update

Comment: @YongShun - you were correct - I was using the wrong (empty) db!

Answer (score 0):

`db.aggregate` is asynchronous. You have to wait for the response. This can be done with the await keyword if you are inside an async function or with the .then function.

Using await:

```js
const sum = await db.aggregate([{ $group : { _id: null, total : {  $sum: { $toDouble : "$amount" }}}}]);
console.log(sum);
```

Using .then

```js
db.aggregate([{ $group : { _id: null, total : {  $sum: { $toDouble : "$amount" }}}}])
.then((sum) => console.log(sum));
```

Comment: maybe my schem definition is wrong: const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
}); because I still am just now getting an empty array using .then